# Samsung Galaxy Tab s8 not responding to correct media query with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am having a strange issue with the Samsung galaxy tab s8. It's weirdly using the mobile media query rather than a tablet. I'm not sure how to work around this with tailwind CSS. The main issue is where it is placed on the screen. The page fits perfectly for all mobile devices. So, my concern is if I try to adjust the Samsung galaxy s8 tab then all mobile devices will move.

TailwindCSS - it is using md:mx-32

```
<div
class="lg:absolute xl:absolute 2xl:absolute 

grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 

lg:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-3

gap-0 md:gap-2 lg:gap-2 xl:gap-2 2xl:gap-2

mt-0 md:mt-10 lg:mt-0 xl:mt-0 2xl:mt-0

top:0 lg:top-56  xl:top-56  2xl:top-80 

font-arial
left:0 md:left-0 lg:left-10 xl:left-10 2xl:left-32

-mx-5 tablet:mx-32 md:mx-32 lg:mx-0 xl:mx-0 2xl:mx-0
mb-0 md:mb-0 lg:mb-10 xl:mb-10 

2xl:mb-96

p-6 md:p-0 lg:p-0 xl:pt-20 2xl:p-0"
```

I downloaded tailwind CDN and I am serving it through a stylesheet. However, I'm not sure how to customize the breakpoint within that sheet.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you provide me a code in tailwind playground? and if possible then please provide me your expected output

Comment: Does it work on other mobiles ?

Comment: What viewport width is shown when on that device if you view this page: https://www.mydevice.io/